# How to block any ads in webvew like adblock or adblock plus in browsers?

Tags: android, webview, adblock, javascript-injection

is there some library for android for block any ads?
how to block using javascript injection?

When I code

```
webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

the ads are shown, but other option of the page not working as the menu or filters.
then how can I block ads but not disable javascript?

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the AdBlock plus Github page offers an [AdblockWebView](https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus-android#webview). To use it, you add this line to your Gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:3.14'
```

And then add this to your layout's XML file:

```
<org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.webview.AdblockWebView
    android:id="@+id/main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

It works just like a regular [WebView component](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#AddingWebView).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this official library:
https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus-android